# Date format in tally xml

Tags: tally

I am trying to create a tally sales voucher from XML api.

If I use a date '20190101' in XML it works fine. But if I use '20190118', it throws error.

Here's my XML:

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <TALLYREQUEST>Import    Data</TALLYREQUEST>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <IMPORTDATA>
            <REQUESTDESC>
                <REPORTNAME>Vouchers</REPORTNAME>
                <STATICVARIABLES>
                    <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>SOAC</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
                </STATICVARIABLES>
            </REQUESTDESC>
            <REQUESTDATA>
                <TALLYMESSAGE   xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
                    <VOUCHER    VCHTYPE="Sales" ACTION="Create" OBJVIEW="Invoice    Voucher View">

                        <DATE>20190101</DATE>
                        <NARRATION>Narration</NARRATION>
                        <PARTYNAME>Cash Cust</PARTYNAME>
                        <VOUCHERTYPENAME>Sales</VOUCHERTYPENAME>
                        <REFERENCE>Reference    No</REFERENCE>
                        <PARTYLEDGERNAME>Cash   Cust</PARTYLEDGERNAME>
                        <BASICBASEPARTYNAME>Cash    Cust</BASICBASEPARTYNAME>
                        <PERSISTEDVIEW>Invoice  Voucher View</PERSISTEDVIEW>
                        <BASICBUYERNAME>Cash    Cust</BASICBUYERNAME>
                        <BASICDATETIMEOFINVOICE>20190101</BASICDATETIMEOFINVOICE>
                        <BASICDATETIMEOFREMOVAL>20190101</BASICDATETIMEOFREMOVAL>
                        <VOUCHERTYPEORIGNAME>Sales</VOUCHERTYPEORIGNAME>
                        <EFFECTIVEDATE>20190101</EFFECTIVEDATE>
                        <HASCASHFLOW>Yes</HASCASHFLOW>
                        <ISINVOICE>Yes</ISINVOICE>

                        <INVOICEORDERLIST.LIST>
                            <BASICORDERDATE>20190101</BASICORDERDATE>
                            <BASICPURCHASEORDERNO>OrderID</BASICPURCHASEORDERNO>
                        </INVOICEORDERLIST.LIST>

                        <LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                            <LEDGERNAME>Cash    Cust</LEDGERNAME>
                            <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                            <ISPARTYLEDGER>Yes</ISPARTYLEDGER>
                            <ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                            <AMOUNT>-40.00</AMOUNT>
                        </LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>

                        <ALLINVENTORYENTRIES.LIST>
                            <STOCKITEMNAME>Beef Burger</STOCKITEMNAME>
                            <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                            <ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                            <RATE>10.00/pcs</RATE>
                            <AMOUNT>40.00</AMOUNT>
                            <ACTUALQTY> 4   pcs</ACTUALQTY>
                            <BILLEDQTY> 4   pcs</BILLEDQTY>
                            <BATCHALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                                <GODOWNNAME>Main    Location</GODOWNNAME>
                                <BATCHNAME>Primary  Batch</BATCHNAME>
                                <AMOUNT>40.00</AMOUNT>
                                <ACTUALQTY> 4   pcs</ACTUALQTY>
                                <BILLEDQTY> 4   pcs</BILLEDQTY>
                            </BATCHALLOCATIONS.LIST>

                            <ACCOUNTINGALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                                <LEDGERNAME>Food    Sales</LEDGERNAME>
                                <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                                <ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                                <AMOUNT>40.00</AMOUNT>
                            </ACCOUNTINGALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                        </ALLINVENTORYENTRIES.LIST>


                    </VOUCHER>
                </TALLYMESSAGE>
            </REQUESTDATA>
        </IMPORTDATA>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

How can I resolve this? Is it because of effective date or any other tag? I'm replacing all the '20190101' with '20190118'.

Here's the error (LOL):

```
<RESPONSE>
 <CREATED>0</CREATED>
 <ALTERED>0</ALTERED>
 <DELETED>0</DELETED>
 <LASTVCHID>0</LASTVCHID>
 <LASTMID>0</LASTMID>
 <COMBINED>0</COMBINED>
 <IGNORED>0</IGNORED>
 <ERRORS>1</ERRORS>
 <CANCELLED>0</CANCELLED>
</RESPONSE>
```

Appreciate any tips and hints.

Comment: Hi Zid, can you share your error?

Comment: @MihranThalhath Yes. Updated in question. LOL. I found the issue. It was the due to Student  Mode. I loaded the license, didn't change anything and the XML works perfect.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. I have also faced the same error more than once ;)

Answer (score 1):

It was the due to Student Mode which allows only few days in a month for transactions and not all days. I loaded the license, didn't change anything and the XML works perfect.